# How to map these DCB structure settings from C to the C# SerialPort class

Tags: c#, c, serial-port

I need to replicate/port the settings for interfacing with a piece of hardware from an example in C++ to C# using its SerialPort class. Since I am not very familiar with the details of COM-port settings, my question is how to map these settings to those of the SerialPort class:

```
HANDLE OpenRS232(const char* ComName, DWORD BaudRate)
{
    HANDLE ComHandle;
    DCB CommDCB;
    COMMTIMEOUTS CommTimeouts;

    ComHandle=CreateFile(ComName, GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if(GetLastError()!=ERROR_SUCCESS) return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    else
    {
        GetCommState(ComHandle, &CommDCB);

        CommDCB.BaudRate=BaudRate;
        CommDCB.Parity=NOPARITY;
        CommDCB.StopBits=ONESTOPBIT;
        CommDCB.ByteSize=8;

        CommDCB.fBinary=1;  //Binary Mode only
        CommDCB.fParity=0;
        CommDCB.fOutxCtsFlow=0;
        CommDCB.fOutxDsrFlow=0;
        CommDCB.fDtrControl=0;
        CommDCB.fDsrSensitivity=0;
        CommDCB.fTXContinueOnXoff=0;
        CommDCB.fOutX=0;
        CommDCB.fInX=0;
        CommDCB.fErrorChar=0;
        CommDCB.fNull=0;
        CommDCB.fRtsControl=RTS_CONTROL_TOGGLE;
        CommDCB.fAbortOnError=0;

        SetCommState(ComHandle, &CommDCB);

        //Set buffer size
        SetupComm(ComHandle, 100, 100);

        //Set up timeout values (very important, as otherwise the program will be very slow)
        GetCommTimeouts(ComHandle, &CommTimeouts);

        CommTimeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout=MAXDWORD;
        CommTimeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier=0;
        CommTimeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant=0;

        SetCommTimeouts(ComHandle, &CommTimeouts);

        return ComHandle;
    }
}
```

Currently, what I have works for communication, but it is running unstable and the communication with the hardware stalls in long-time endurance/stability tests. Here is the excerpt from the hardware controller factory that sets up the serial port:

```
    private static SerialPort _serialPort = new SerialPort();
    private string portName = "COM23";
    private int baudRate = 9600;
    private Parity portParity = Parity.None;
    private int dataBits = 8;
    private StopBits stopBits = StopBits.One;
    int serialPortReceiveTimeout = 30000;
    static private int TxRxBufferLength = 9;

    public ControllerFactory()
    {
        _serialPort = new SerialPort();
        _serialPort.PortName = portName;
        _serialPort.BaudRate = baudRate;
        _serialPort.Parity = portParity;
        _serialPort.DataBits = dataBits;
        _serialPort.StopBits = stopBits;
        _serialPort.ReadTimeout = serialPortReceiveTimeout;
        _serialPort.ReceivedBytesThreshold = TxRxBufferLength;

        try
        {
            _serialPort.Open();
            _serialPort.DiscardOutBuffer();
            _serialPort.DiscardInBuffer();
            Controller = new Controller(_serialPort, Address, TxRxBufferLength, ControllerClockFrequency);
        } catch { }
```

**UPDATE:**

I thought I was going to try and keep the type of controller obscure, but there really isn't any reason to:

It is a TMCM-3110 from Trinamics and you can find the firmware manual [here](https://www.trinamic.com/fileadmin/assets/Products/Modules_Documents/TMCM-3110_TMCL-firmware_manual_V105.pdf). Furthermore the code example is [here](https://www.trinamic.com/fileadmin/assets/Support/Software/TMCLTestVC__.zip), which is linked from the code examples [here](https://www.trinamic.com/support/software/). I have not yet contacted Trinamics support, as I have only realized that the stability issues that I am having are likely caused by the incorrect COM-settings.

Regarding these stability issues:

By stalling I meant that the software crashes due to some of the data bytes not being received correctly. This causes problems with the checksum value being incorrect (see the example code for details on its calculation) and also leads to serial-port timeout, which eventually causes the process to crash. Unfortunately I have not yet been able to really identify, where the problem stems from, but I suspect it is the wrong serial-port settings.

Here is my C# code that I am using for handling the communication with the TMCM controller. As you can see it is more or less a 1-to-1 port from the C++ code:

```
    static readonly object locker = new object();
    private int sendCmdAndCheckResult(byte Address, byte Command, byte CommandType, byte MotorNr, int Value)
    {
        lock (locker) // this part needs to finish with out another thread interrupting, so that the sent value and the return value belong to the same command from the same thread. See firmware manual.
        {
            sendCmd(Address, Command, CommandType, MotorNr, Value);
            readReturnMessageToBuffer();
            checkReturnedStatus();
            Thread.Sleep(10);
            return getReturnedValue();
        }
    }

    private void sendCmd(byte Address, byte Command, byte CommandType, byte MotorNr, int Value)
    {
        TxBuffer[0] = Address;
        TxBuffer[1] = (byte)Command;
        TxBuffer[2] = (byte)CommandType;
        TxBuffer[3] = (byte)MotorNr;
        TxBuffer[4] = (byte)(Value >> 24);
        TxBuffer[5] = (byte)(Value >> 16);
        TxBuffer[6] = (byte)(Value >> 8);
        TxBuffer[7] = (byte)(Value & 0xff);
        TxBuffer[8] = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            TxBuffer[8] += TxBuffer[i];

        Log($"TmclController: Sending  COM-Port Buffer: {ByteArrayToString(TxBuffer)}");

        if (ComPort.IsOpen)
            ComPort.Write(TxBuffer, 0, TxRxBufferLength);
    }

    private void readReturnMessageToBuffer()
    {
        byte Checksum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < TxRxBufferLength; i++)
        {
            if(ComPort.IsOpen)
            RxBuffer[i] = (byte) ComPort.ReadByte(); // read byte for byte synchronously; ReadByte() is block and returns only, when it has read a byte; this method is inefficient, but the easiest way to achieve a blocking read of the returned message; a better way would be to use asychronous reading of serial ports using e.g. the SerialPort.ReceivedBytesThreshold Property and SerialPort.DataReceived Event
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            Checksum += RxBuffer[i];

        Log($"TmclController: Received COM-Port Buffer: {ByteArrayToString(RxBuffer)}");

        if (Checksum != RxBuffer[8])
        {
            InvalidOperationException er = new InvalidOperationException("Returned Checksum from TMCL controller is incorrect.");
            throw er;
        }
    }

    private int getReturnedValue()
    {
        return (int)((RxBuffer[4] << 24) | (RxBuffer[5] << 16) | (RxBuffer[6] << 8) | RxBuffer[7]);
    }
```

Comment: 'but it is running unstable and the communication with the hardware stalls' can you be a bit more specific?  Does it recover from the stalls at all?  What application-level serial protocol are you using?

Comment: Martin it is C#. When see the data threshold I know that the DataReceived event is used. It does not work properly unfortunately

Comment: The handshaking it uses is very unusual and not supported by SerialPort.  The buffer sizes it uses are excessively small, that might be one reason.  The C# code does not set it at all and that is a very serious mistake, at least you must use Handshake.None.  Not otherwise an explanation for longterm instability.  It uses *no* timeout but the C# code does, getting that wrong is not good but the TimeoutException is impossible to miss.  Be sure to not swallow it.  Using ReceivedBytesThreshold is an excellent way to cause instability.   You must use the ErrorReceived event to detect data loss.

Comment: @MartinJames I have updated my question regarding the "stalling".

Comment: @HansPassant Unfortunately I do not really understand the phrase: "Not otherwise an explanation for longterm instability." I am getting TimeoutExceptions, which I tried to circumvent by increasing the timeout to 30seconds. Regarding TimeoutException, ReceivedBytesThreshold and ErrorReceived and error handling: I don't really know how to do error-handling, since the problems seem to be in the reply from the controller. And it seems to me, that if I did not get the reply correctly, I will not know, what its state is afterwards ...

Comment: @PeterJ_01 I have added the code for the acutal communication. I am aware that the ReceivedBytesThreshold is currently not being used. However in theory it should work, since I know from the firmware manual that the answer from the controller will be 9 Bytes long. Could you elaborate on what you mean by "It does not work properly unfortunately"?

Comment: From your comment - Data received event does not work properly. The best way is to have the background worker reading the port all the time. Blocking read did not work for me as well. Background worker + custom events and you are done :). I am a beginner in C# but this approach works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am a beginner in C# but wrote some code using serial ports (for example an oscilloscope application communicating over the VCP). Unfortunately the easy way (DataReceived event ...) does not work. To make it work you need to write your own background worker getting the data from the stream or just reading the data from the serial port as they arrive. Even the second approach works - I have tested on windows 8M data rate for about two weeks without any problems.